# How do I add pressure and adjust rebound on older mountain bike forks?

Tags: fork, suspension

[image]

It doesn't have design of modern forks and I can't find a tutorial online for a fork like this. Any tips?

Comment: I hope the brake is just temporarily disabled ;)

Comment: @Michael both brakes!

Comment: Haha yes, I took the wheels off for transport.

Answer (score 8):

You can easilly find the manual just by googling the visible words from your photo "Marzocchi Bomber 2001", for example https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1728712/Marzocchi-Bomber-2001.html  Adjustments are on page 10 and in detail from page 24. A schematic picture is on page 14.

There are air and coil variants.
What you can adjust in the air ones is the air pressure and the oil level, which in turn determines the air volume.

However from the picture on [page 32](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1728712/Marzocchi-Bomber-2001.html?page=32#manual) it appears to me you have the coil variant and that by getting out the dust cap on the left crown (on the right in the photo) you will get to the coil preload adjustment (use the Allen key). A flat screwdriver should then suffice to adjust the rebound cartridge.

Make sure which exact variant you have. The picture tells a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much! What is the extension part to attach the pump to the fork called?

Comment: An air pump connects to a Schrader valve located on top of the fork leg under a cap. Some Bombers are dual air and have Schrader valves on too of each leg. For this one uses a high pressure shock pump which has a pressure gauge on it and typically has a means to fine tune the pressure by means of a button valve that releases small amounts of air.

Comment: @justin I believe your pump spring (coil)-based. Not air based. Tjerefore, you cannot pump your fork. But do consuůt the manual yourself and check the exact type of your fork. It should be written on your fork somewhere, it is just not visible in your photo.

Comment: @Jeff I believe there is no valve on this specific fork. It has a metal spring.

Comment: @Vladimir Could be. I have a Bomber All Mountain 4. Has dual air. For the OP, if it is a spring fork nearly the only adjustment is preload which will affect sag and the plush/firm feel of the fork.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it is a metal coil. When I removed the dust covers, there were valve like thinks under them they looked like Schrader valves with the thread in the inside.

Comment: @justin There is no need guessing. I could be wrong from the single picture. Is there anything more written on the fork? Did you compare the fork twith the manual I linked? There are like 6 variants described there with their names and settings instructions, recommended pressures end everything you need.